# Understanding matlabFunction

Tags: matlab, function, ode

I have been using `matlabFunction` rather extensively in my computational physics class, and I was hoping someone could help me understand what exactly is going on with this command (is `matlabFunction` a command?). I have read [what the MathWorks website provides](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) regarding `matlabFunction`, but was hoping for some clarification.

For instance, we dealt with Lorenz equations, a chaotic system. This is a system of differential equations:

```
dx/dt = s*(y-x), dy/dt = -x*z+r*x-y, dz/dt = x*y-b*z.
```

We used `matlabFunction` as such:

```
matlabFunction([s*(y-x);-x*z+r*x-y; x*y-b*z],...
    'vars', {t,[x;y;z],[s;r;b]},...
    'file', 'Example2');
```

I understand that `[s*(y-x);-x*z+r*x-y; x*y-b*z]` is a column vector containing our unknown functions (in this case, they are derivatives with respect to time), which we use to approximate the functions x(t), y(t), and z(t) with `ode45`.

My question is, how is `[s*(y-x);-x*z+r*x-y; x*y-b*z]` related to `{t,[x;y;z],[s;r;b]}`? Evidently the order matters, but I don't quite understand this. I think I would understand this if I knew the relationship between the two.

If you feel that I have not provided enough information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code (excluding the `file`-parameter) generates the following output:

```
matlabFunction([s*(y-x);-x*z+r*x-y; x*y-b*z],'vars',{t,[x;y;z],[s;r;b]})

ans = 

    @(t,in2,in3)[-in3(1,:).*(in2(1,:)-in2(2,:));-in2(2,:)+in3(2,:).*in2(1,:)-in2(1,:).*in2(3,:);-in3(3,:).*in2(3,:)+in2(1,:).*in2(2,:)]
```

The cell `{t,[x;y;z],[s;r;b]}` defines that the first input argument of the function is `t`. The second input argument `in2` is a 3 element vector containing `[x;y;z]` and the third input argument in3 is a 3 element vector containing `[s;r;b]`

Compare the output to the following, to see the relation between your symbolic variables and input arguments:

```
    matlabFunction([s*(y-x);-x*z+r*x-y; x*y-b*z],'vars',{t,x,y,z,s,r,b})

ans = 

    @(t,x,y,z,s,r,b)[-s.*(x-y);-y+r.*x-x.*z;-b.*z+x.*y]
```

Comment: Okay. Now I have a question that pertains to ode45. When I pass this function through ode45, with some initial conditions, does ode45 read the derivative -s.*(x-y) as approximating the unknown function x; the same thing being said of -y+r.*x-x.*z and y, and -b.*z+x.*y and z? Also, the vector [s;r;b] is just a vector of parameters.